# Laravel5: Complex hasManyThrouh self referencing relation (with aliases and SQL calculations)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, model, has-many-through, relation

I am rebuilding a project in laravel and my current problem is to define a complex self referencing hasManyThrough relation with table aliasing and SQL calculations.

This relation should find related merchants depending on a downward sum of matching tags. The more same tags the models have, the more related they are.

So far, so good. In my old project, I just wrote down the following suitable SQL query:

```
SELECT source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id, COUNT(target_merchant.id) /
((
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagged WHERE model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = source_merchant.id) + 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagged WHERE model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = target_merchant.id) 
) /2 ) as similarity 
FROM merchants source_merchant 
LEFT JOIN tagged source_merchant_tags ON (
    source_merchant.id = source_merchant_tags.model_id AND 
    source_merchant_tags.model = 'Merchant'
) 
INNER JOIN tagged target_merchant_tags ON (
    source_merchant_tags.tag_id = target_merchant_tags.tag_id 
    AND (source_merchant_tags.model = 'Merchant' AND target_merchant_tags.model = 'Merchant') 
    AND (source_merchant_tags.model_id != target_merchant_tags.model_id)
)  
LEFT JOIN merchants target_merchant ON (
    target_merchant_tags.model_id = target_merchant.id AND target_merchant_tags.model = 'Merchant'
) 
WHERE source_merchant.id = 2 
GROUP BY source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id 
ORDER BY similarity DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Best would be to catch something like

```
public function related_merchants() {
    return $this->hasManyThroug(relations_stuff_i_cannot_imagine...)
        ->selectRaw("SELECT source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id, COUNT(target_merchant.id) /
        ((
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagged WHERE model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = source_merchant.id) + 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagged WHERE model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = target_merchant.id) 
        ) /2 ) as similarity")
        ->groupBy('source_merchant.id', 'target_merchant.id ')
        ->orderBy('similarity')
        ->limit(5);
}
```

That's it :-) Unfortunally, I can't find a solution because I do not know, how to define suitable relation parameters in `hasManyThrough()`...

**Edit** - Trying to build Laravel query as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077359/3545267):

```
public function getRelatedMerchantsAttribute() {

    return $this->from('merchants AS source_merchant')
        ->selectRaw('source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id, COUNT(target_merchant.id) /
            ((
                (' . DB::table('tagged')->whereRaw("model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = source_merchant.id")->count() . ') +
                ' .  DB::table('tagged')->whereRaw("model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = target_merchant.id")->count() . ')
                /2 ) AS similarity')
        ->lefJoin('tagged AS source_merchant_tags', function ($join) {
            $join->on('source_merchant.id', '=', 'source_merchant_tags.model_id')
            ->on('source_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant');
        })
        ->join('tagged AS target_merchant_tags', function ($join) {
            $join->on('source_merchant_tags.tag_id', '=', 'target_merchant_tags.tag_id')
            ->on('source_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant')
            ->on('target_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant')
            ->on('source_merchant_tags.model_id', '!=', 'target_merchant_tags.model_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('merchants AS target_merchant', function ($join) {
            $join->on('target_merchant_tags.model_id ', '=', 'target_merchant.id')
            ->on('target_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant');
        })
        ->whereRaw('source_merchant.id = ?', [ $this->id ])
        ->groupBy('source_merchant.id', 'target_merchant.id ')
        ->orderBy('similarity')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();

}
```

This solution is not working yet because of:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'merchants.id'
in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tagged`
where model = 'Merchant' AND model_id = merchants.id)
```

**Edit** - Using [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077359/3545267) produces the following Laravel error:

**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number. SQL:**

```
select source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id, 
COUNT(target_merchant.id) /
((
    (select COUNT(*) from `tagged` where `model` = Merchant and `model_id` = source_merchant.id) +
    (select COUNT(*) from `tagged` where `model` = Merchant and `model_id` = target_merchant.id)
) /2 ) AS similarity
from `merchants` as `source_merchant`
left join `tagged` as `source_merchant_tags` on 
    `source_merchant`.`id` = `source_merchant_tags`.`model_id`
    and `source_merchant_tags`.`model` = Merchant
inner join `tagged` as `target_merchant_tags` on 
    `source_merchant_tags`.`tag_id` = `target_merchant_tags`.`tag_id` 
    and `source_merchant_tags`.`model` = Merchant
    and `target_merchant_tags`.`model` = 2
    and `source_merchant_tags`.`model_id` != `target_merchant_tags`.`model_id` 
left join `merchants` as `target_merchant` on 
    `target_merchant_tags`.`model_id` = `target_merchant`.`id`
    and `target_merchant_tags`.`model` = ?
where `source_merchant`.`id` = ? 
group by `source_merchant`.`id`, `target_merchant`.`id`
order by `similarity` desc
limit 5
```

I'm even wondering why the current model id is used here: `and target_merchant_tags.model = 2`...

Take a look at this screenshot. The conditional parameter 'Merchant' becomes the current model ID, in this case it's 2 (selected text). The two parameters in the red circles remain empty. What's wrong here?

[image: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number]

Comment: What model contains the relationship? What model should the relationship return?

Comment: Ist's both the model Merchant. Take a look at the initial query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a relationship is the right choice for your situation. The source and target merchants aren't really *related* in the Laravel/Eloquent sense, since the common tags are only used to determine the order.

I would just convert your raw SQL to a Laravel query and rename your method to `getRelatedMerchantsAttribute`. Then you can access them with `$merchant->relatedMerchants`.

Try this query:

```php
$sourceCount = DB::table('tagged')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
    ->where('model', 'Merchant')
    ->where('model_id', DB::raw('source_merchant.id'));
$targetCount = DB::table('tagged')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
    ->where('model', 'Merchant')
    ->where('model_id', DB::raw('target_merchant.id'));
$this->from('merchants AS source_merchant')
    ->addBinding($sourceCount->getBindings(), 'select')
    ->addBinding($targetCount->getBindings(), 'select')
    ->selectRaw('source_merchant.id, target_merchant.id, COUNT(target_merchant.id) /
    ((
        (' . $sourceCount->toSql() . ') +
        (' .  $targetCount->toSql() . '))
        /2 ) AS similarity')
    ->leftJoin('tagged AS source_merchant_tags', function ($join) {
        $join->on('source_merchant.id', '=', 'source_merchant_tags.model_id')
            ->where('source_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant');
    })
    ->join('tagged AS target_merchant_tags', function ($join) {
        $join->on('source_merchant_tags.tag_id', '=', 'target_merchant_tags.tag_id')
            ->where('source_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant')
            ->where('target_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant')
            ->on('source_merchant_tags.model_id', '!=', 'target_merchant_tags.model_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('merchants AS target_merchant', function ($join) {
        $join->on('target_merchant_tags.model_id', '=', 'target_merchant.id')
            ->where('target_merchant_tags.model', '=', 'Merchant');
    })
    ->where('source_merchant.id', $this->id)
    ->groupBy('source_merchant.id', 'target_merchant.id')
    ->orderByDesc('similarity')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Okay, seems legit. Unfortunally, it's a little bit tricky to convert the query to a laravel query because of nested tablenames in the subquerries. I'm going nuts...

Comment: Try the query in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I tried this query and get a parameter count error and a model id binding I can't understand... Check my editied initial question above to get more details.

Comment: I meant `$merchant->relatedMerchants` like that.

Comment: I assume you ran the query with `paginate()`? How exactly?

Comment: I got it, you defined a mutator. In my Merchant model there is a method `getRelatedMerchantsAttribute()`. But calling this method in my MerchantController with `$related = $merchant->relatedMerchants();` produces an error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::relatedMerchants does not exist.`

And I do not use any `paginate()`. I'm using `$merchant = Merchant::where('slug', $slug)->first();`.

Comment: You have to access it as a property: `$related = $merchant->relatedMerchants;`

Comment: Ouch, sure... But the error remains. Take a look at my second edit and the screenshot in my origin question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170289/discussion-between-dong3000-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Comment: Oh, yea, this one worked, what a ride! I'll crumble your code to retrace every step. Thx!